# Difference in tf-idf values in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, normalization, matrix

I am playing around in R to find the `tf-idf` values.

I have a set of `documents` like:

```
D1 = "The sky is blue."
D2 = "The sun is bright."
D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright."
```

I want to create a matrix like this:

```
   Docs      blue    bright       sky       sun
   D1 tf-idf 0.0000000 tf-idf 0.0000000
   D2 0.0000000 tf-idf 0.0000000 tf-idf
   D3 0.0000000 tf-idf tf-idf tf-idf
```

So, my code in `R`:

```
library(tm)
docs <- c(D1 = "The sky is blue.", D2 = "The sun is bright.", D3 = "The sun in the sky is bright.")

dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs)) #Make a corpus object from a text vector
#Clean the text
dd <- tm_map(dd, stripWhitespace)
dd <- tm_map(dd, tolower)
dd <- tm_map(dd, removePunctuation)
dd <- tm_map(dd, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
dd <- tm_map(dd, stemDocument)
dd <- tm_map(dd, removeNumbers)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
as.matrix(dtm)
      Terms
            Docs      blue    bright       sky       sun
            D1 0.7924813 0.0000000 0.2924813 0.0000000
            D2 0.0000000 0.2924813 0.0000000 0.2924813
            D3 0.0000000 0.1949875 0.1949875 0.1949875
```

If I do a hand calculation then the matrix should be:

```
            Docs  blue      bright       sky       sun
            D1    0.2385    0.0000000  0.0880    0.0000000
            D2    0.0000000 0.0880     0.0000000 0.0880
            D3    0.0000000 0.058      0.058     0.058
```

I am calculating like say `blue` as `tf` = `1/2 = 0.5` and `idf` as `log(3/1) = 0.477121255`. Therefore `tf-idf = tf*idf = 0.5*0.477 = 0.2385`. In this way, I am calculating the other `tf-idf` values. Now, I am wondering, why I am getting different results in the matrix of hand calculation and in the matrix of R? Which gives the correct results? Am I doing something wrong in hand calculation or is there something wrong in my R code?

Comment: I notice you are using base-10 logarithms in your calculations.  This motivated me to check that your matrix is, up to the limited precision in which you report it, exactly $0.30$ times the one given by `R`. Finally, I see that the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) takes pains to state that "mathematically the base of the log function does not matter and constitutes a constant multiplicative factor towards the overall result," suggesting that only *relative* tf-idf values have any meaning.

Comment: @whuber sorry, I cannot understand your last sentence. What do you mean by `relative tf-idf` values?

Comment: "Relative" is used in the sense of the Wikipedia quotation: although the actual values are without meaning, their *ratios* (which are invariant when all values are rescaled by a "constant [nonzero] multiplicative factor") are well-determined.  In this sense your output agrees perfectly with `R`'s output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the comments: The difference in result is because `R` calculates `log of base 2` while I am calculating `log of base 10`.